# iPhone how to display gallery of photos from core data?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data, photo-gallery

I'm looking for an open source photo gallery that **allows to load photos from core data**.

Here's what I want to do:

- Give the gallery a core data object with binary image data
- have the gallery inflate the image when it is time to display it

So far I was unable to find an open source gallery that does this. I tried to modify FGallery, but it crashes very often for me when I try to use core data as image sources. I'm unable to find out what's causing this behavior and have to abandon that approach.

I checked EGOPhotoViewer, but it only has support for local and network images.

**Is there an open source photo gallery that is developed for images stored in core data ?**

Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Core Data is just a way to store your Data as you do it in Your document directory or Resource and it behaves like local data only, if you were using EGOPhotoViewer you can directly pass your image data in Uiimageview on slide or button tap its just that the image will be in binary format use:

```
uiimage initwithdata:<your image data from core data>
```

as per fetching the image data saved in your core data you can use ID or some parameter which is unique for your every image saved in core data.